# Splashscreen flutter, prevent back button

Tags: android, ios, flutter, splash-screen

I've made a custom Splashscreen but when I press back button from statless widget, it will go back to Splashcreen "Stateful widget". I've tried WillPopBack but it not work or at least I was not able to use it. How to prevent statless widget to go back to stateful widget?
Here my code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue, fontFamily: 'Monserrat'),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
      Navigator.of(context).push(
        PageRouteBuilder(
          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
              Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
            return MainScreen();
          },
          transitionsBuilder: (BuildContext context,
              Animation<double> animation,
              Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
              Widget child) {
            return Align(
              child: FadeTransition(
                opacity: animation,
                child: child,
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return [...]
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return [...]
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pushReplacement` instead of `push` like

```dart
  super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement( //< this
        PageRouteBuilder(
          transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
          pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation,
              Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
            return MainScreen();
          },
```

More about [push](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html) and [pushReplacement](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html)